# How to add custom validation to ensure unique value for one of the childView's Properties in custom plugin?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have a custom plugin which has a table with rows. I have Add button to add a row. While adding I want to ensure uniqueness of a property value. By default  `childView.Properties.Add` has `IsRequired = false/true` but there is nothing to check if the value is unique.

Please can someone help me on this?

Comment: you need to look into IValidateEntityPipeline and PlugIn.Validation.PolicySet-1.0.0.json. you might need to do customization based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link helped me. 
https://websterian.com/2018/10/10/sitecore-commerce-adding-an-entirely-new-entity-part-1-commerce-engine-and-business-tools/

Have a look at validationError in DoActionAddBrandBlock.cs.